# Sort a Huge Number of Documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

When I would like to retrieve a huge number of documents from elasticsearch index, I always use  scan and scroll technique from elasticsearch (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html) as follows:

```
conn = Elasticsearch( hosts = HOSTS )

the_query = { 'query': { 'match_all': {  } }, 'sort': { 'created_at': { 'order': 'asc' } } } # would like sort the documents according to the 'created_at' date

scanResp = conn.search( index=TARGET_INDEX, doc_type=TARGET_DOC_TYPE, body=the_query, search_type='scan', scroll='10m' )
scrollId = scanResp['_scroll_id']
doc_num = 1

response = conn.scroll( scroll_id = scrollId, scroll='10m' )

while ( len( response['hits']['hits'] ) > 0 ):
    for item in response['hits']['hits']:
        print '\tDocument ' + str(doc_num) + ' of ' + str( response['hits']['total'] )
        doc_num += 1

        # ====================
        #   Process the item
        # ====================
        the_doc = item['_source']


    # end for item
    scrollId = response['_scroll_id']
    if doc_num >= response['hits']['total']:
        break
    response = conn.scroll( scroll_id = scrollId, scroll='10m' )
# end of while
```

However, as the elasticsearch documentation mentioned, the retrieved documents will not be sorted so the result is not what I want.

My question:
How can I sort a huge number of documents in Elasticsearch?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling is expensive when iterating through a sorted list, but if you insist, remove the 'scan' search_type from your query. scan disables sort when you are scrolling.